# Spark Submit Issue

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a fat jar on a Spark cluster using Spark submit.
I made the cluster using "spark-ec2" executable in Spark bundle on AWS.

The command I am using to run the jar file is

```
bin/spark-submit --class edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main --master yarn-cluster ../src1/big-data-hw2-assembly-1.0.jar
```

In the beginning it was giving me the error that at least one of the **HADOOP_CONF_DIR** or **YARN_CONF_DIR** environment variable must be set.
I didn't know what to set them to, so I used the following command

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/mapreduce/conf
```

Now the error has changed to

```
Could not load YARN classes. This copy of Spark may not have been compiled with YARN support.
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

The home directory structure is as follows

```
ephemeral-hdfs  hadoop-native  mapreduce  persistent-hdfs  scala  spark  spark-ec2  src1  tachyon
```

I even set the YARN_CONF_DIR variable to the same value as HADOOP_CONF_DIR, but the error message is not changing. I am unable to find any documentation that highlights this issue, most of them just mention these two variables and give no further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile spark against Yarn to use it.

Follow the steps explained here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html

Maven:

```
build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.x -Dhadoop.version=2.x.x -DskipTests clean package
```

SBT:

```
build/sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.x assembly
```

You can also download a pre-compiled version here: http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html (choose a "pre-built for Hadoop")

Answer (score 1):

Download prebuilt spark which supports hadoop 2.X versions from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

The `--master` argument should be: `--master spark://hostname:7077` where *hostname* is the name of your Spark master server. You can also specify this value as `spark.master` in the spark-defaults.conf file and leave out the `--master` argument when using Spark submit from the command line. Including the `--master` argument will override the value set (if exists) in the spark-defaults.conf file.

Reference: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/configuration.html