# Can we run apache spark 1.1.0 on yarn-cluster?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am using spark 1.1.0 on ubuntu. While submitting to spark with yarn using below command

> ./bin/spark-submit --class path.to.your.Class --master yarn-cluster [options]  [app options]

I am getting the error

> Could not load YARN classes. This copy of Spark may not have been compiled with YARN support.
>   Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output

The solution I found is running another version of spark which is precompiled with yarn.It will take much effort to migrate project to recent versions.
Can I run my jar on yarn cluster with same, spark-1.1.0 version ? If yes, How ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585307/spark-submit-issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the same version of spark in both yarn cluster and in ubuntu to run the spark app successfully.

Using Different version during development and deployment will generate issues.